# In a vtk rectilinear grid 2dim data viz, what is the order of scalar values in the .vtk file?

Tags: visualization, heatmap, vtk, visit-llnl

I am trying to create a simple `.vtk` file to visualize it with `VisIt`.

It will be a **2D pseudocolor plot**.

I start with a rectilinar 2D grid and I programatically write to a .vtk file the x-coordinates values (1 per line), then the y-coordinates values (1 per line).

Then the z-coordinate is then written because it has to be written, but the plot will be 2D (a 2D heatmap).

**I then reach the point of confusion. The scalars values.**

I have a 2D Python-numpy array of double precision values.
The first dimension represents the x-axis, the 2nd dimension represents the y-axis.

I.e. `arr[i, j]` represents the value which shall appear at location `x[i]` and `y[j]`.

**How do I list (1 per line) vertically downwards this 2D array of values?**

x-axis varies the fastest and y-axis varies slower?

I couldn't find this in any .vtk tutorial online, or I haven't searched well enough.

I can elaborate on any of the above points if something is not clear.

Thank you!